# Sort items in folder by date...only for that folder!

Tags: finder

Normally I have all my Finder sorted alphabetically but, for some folders, order by date would be better but changing order in those folder will change order for all Finder...

Is there a way to sort items in a different way only for that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In El Capitan they added an option to sort photos in Albums by newest or older!!

It's in menu bar under View -> Sort -> by name, older or newer!!

Answer (score 1):

You can only specify the sort order for the top-most folder in any given view.
If you want to sort a folder in a folder to a different view, you would need to open it in a new window…

Main folder sorted by Name, sub folder by Date…

[image]

Comment: That's a solution, the best would be something permanent so, every time I open that folder, it's sorted as setted before. I try to leave the question open for a while...

Comment: It is permanent - it just needs both views open at once to see it.

Comment: It's true, but if there was a way to do that in the same window it would be better...

Comment: If there was… but there isn't ;-) A good example would be to sort a hierarchy of folders by date then watch what happens as the last modifieds get changed over time.

Comment: Is this answer still correct for Catalina?